# Storing chat application data (messages)

Tags: iphone, chat

I want to create an application in which chat facility will be provided. In this application a user can chat with another online user through webservices.

Here I am hitting server and get the data in XML format:

```
 <GetMessagesResult>
 <Chat>
 <Users>
 <New>0</New>
 </Users>
 <Messages>
 <Msg>
 <U>Rajesh Patel</U>
 <M>hi friends</M>
 <M>call me when u got this message</M>
 </Msg>

 <Msg>
 <U>Mitesh Patel</U>
 <M>hi vijay</M>
 <M>am john</M>
 <M>from office</M></Msg>
 </Messages>
 </Chat>
 </GetMessagesResult>
```

Here 2 online users Mitesh and Rajesh and I want to store all the data like user name and their messages. Also I want to store messages which I have sent to a particular user and want to show them in a tableview.

Can anyone tell me how to store this data?

Comment: Try CoreData or SQLite directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Till . I know how to store these data in to CoreData or SQLite but confuse in how to show in a table view means like another chat application ....can u please tell how the schema ot table for this...Or any link to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for simple chat application

```
***User***

**id***   |  **Username** | **Password** 
=================================================================
________________________________________________

***Chat Room***

**id**   |  **Name**
=================================================================
________________________________________________

***Chat Room Member***

**id**   |  **UserId** | **ChatRoomId** 
=================================================================
________________________________________________
***Chat Table***

**id**  |  **MessageId**  |  **ChatRoomId**
=================================================================
________________________________________________

***Message Table***

**id**   |  **UserId**   |  **MessageText**  |  **Date**
=================================================================
________________________________________________
```

For each chat you should define a chat room and put users in chat room Member table in next step put message data in Message table and in last step put your data in Chat Table.